# Can't bind to 'ngSwitchDefault' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-switch, ng-template

I get the error:

> Can't bind to 'ngSwitchDefault' since it isn't a known property of
>   'ng-template'

Before I go on: this is ***not*** a duplicate of [Angular2 - "Can't bind to 'ngSwitchWhen' since it isn't a known property of 'template'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719113/angular2-cant-bind-to-ngswitchwhen-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tem)

The ngSwitchWhen binds perfectly nice just the way that I used it. The problem is with the ngSwitchDefault, which I can only use in it's sytactic suggared verison ***ngSwitchDefault**. But since I have another structural directive on the matter (***ngIf**) I would like to use the "Template-[ngSwitchDefault]"-Version, which gives me the aforementioned error.

**Question: Any reason why I can use [ngSwitchCase], but not [ngSwitchDefault] ?**

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="field.myType">
      <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="'something'">
        <div *ngIf="fieldIsVisibile[field.name]">
          Somthing special: {{field.name}}
        </div>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template [ngSwitchDefault]>
        <div *ngIf="fieldIsVisibile[field.name]">
          Regular: {{field.name}}
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it should just be

```
<ng-template ngSwitchDefault>
```

because `ngSwitchDefault` doesn't get a value passed and doesn't have an `@Input()`